# Solspace Friends - Friend Request Hook

Tags: solspace, hook, solspace-friends

Is there a hook I can use when a friend request is made in Solspace Friends add-on?

After a friend request is made, I want to send a notification to the "friendee" (e.g. by email, Ajax notification, etc.).

The current [list of hooks](http://www.solspace.com/docs/friends/extension_hooks/) do not seem to offer me a hook that I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not in the list of hooks, and no hooks are found in the Friends core files where you need one, then the hook doesn't exist.

I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category (with an explanation of why and how you would use the hook). It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions